# Silverstripe display logic for Front-end/Bootstrap forms

Tags: forms, logic, frontend, silverstripe

Silverstripe Display Logic works perfectly on forms in the CMS but I cannot get it to work on forms in the front end, specifically Bootstrap forms.

It will hide the element but won't display it when logic is applied.

```
//If the wetsuit dropdown is equal to custom then show the fins numerical field.

DisplayLogicWrapper::create(NumericField::create("Fins","Fins"))->displayIf("Wetsuit")->isEqualTo('Custom')->end(),
```

I see it just needs display to change from none to block. 
Is there a way to do this so that it will keep the state on page reload as well? The drop down value will be saved as a DB entry.

EDIT: This works in the CMS but doesn't work in the front end - `Custom` is part of the enum values.

```
DropdownField::create("Wetsuit","Wetsuit")
            ->setSource(singleton('DiveEquipment')->dbObject('Wetsuit')->enumValues())
            ->setEmptyString('Select one'), 


NumericField::create('Fins','Fins')
            ->displayIf('Wetsuit')
            ->isEqualTo('Custom')
            ->end(),
```

EDIT2: Working with SilversTripe 3.5, Bootstrap Forms 1.20 and Display Logic 1.0.8

1.0.8 is very outdated though.

Comment: So if you change the `Wetsuit` dropdown value to `Custom`, the `Fins` field isn't being displayed? Have you verified that the actual dropdown values contain `Custom` ? Maybe you need to post your Dropdown creation code.

Comment: That is correct yes. It will show in the CMS but not in the front-end. The value does contain `Custom`. 
I see there are JS errors in the front end. Will update OP.

Comment: I guess you need to include entwine…

Comment: It is included? `/framework/thirdparty/jquery-entwine` Unless I am missing something and need to included it elsewhere? Never used entwine before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `DisplayLogicWrapper` for most fields… It's meant for fields like `UploadField`.

Have you tried this?

```
NumericField::create('Fins','Fins')
    ->displayIf('Wetsuit')
    ->isEqualTo('Custom')
    ->end(),
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I've tried with and without `DisplayLogicWrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Not the issue here, but it's worth noting that a bug exists in Display Logic 1.3 and lower where the custom templates exist in /templates/ not /templates/forms/, causing precedence issues.

If you're experiencing problems with a FieldGroup not rendering the correct template or whatnot. Upgrading to Display Logic 1.4 will resolve this.

Comment: Just a note on this. I downgraded to version 1.0.8 of Display Logic and it works. It doesn't use the traditional bootstrap theme but it is working nonetheless. So SilverStripe 3.5, Bootstrap Forms 1.20 and Display Logic 1.0.8 works. Quite outdated but it seems to work for me

Comment: I bet if you copied the Bootstrap items from it:
https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic/tree/1.0.8/templates

To your themes/{mytheme} and upgraded to the latest DisplayLogic. You'd have the latest version and everything working. Seems the older version had built-in Bootstrap support.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include jQuery and jQuery Entwine for this to work on the frontend. This is untested but should resolve your issue.

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        Requirements::javascript(THIRDPARTY_DIR . '/jquery/jquery.js');
        Requirements::javascript(THIRDPARTY_DIR . '/jquery-entwine/dist/jquery.entwine-dist.js');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, they are both included already though. I can see them in the page source.

Comment: What order are they included? Display Logic should be after jQuery and jQuery Entwine.

Comment: The order is Jquery 1.11.3, Bootstrap Forms, Jquery Entwine, Display Logic. Using Jquery 1.12 was throwing the JS errors. Using 1.11.3 doesn't throw any errors but it still doesn't work.